# Ember communicate between child components

Tags: ember.js, components, ember-cli

I'm trying to make a header component, which has several inside components,
such as a button, and one of them opens a side menu that is a child component also.

How can target an action of one child component to another child component?

In this case, target the open action in the button component to the overlay component?

```
{{#header-block class="main-nav"}}

  {{button-icon icon="fi-torso" class="nav-action left" openMenu=(action "open" target=) }}

  {{#overlay-block}}
    {{#side-menu}}
      <p>side menu one</p>
    {{/side-menu}}
  {{/overlay-block}}

{{/header-block}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not using the public API. You may have read this before, but Ember's components follow the "data down, actions up" approach. In order to do what you want, you have to send an action from the button component to your controller, mutate some data based on that action, then pass that data into the overlay component. There can be no direct communication between the two components.

Comment: There's plenty of articles out there on this top. [This one](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/04/26/inter-component/) might give you some ideas.